# Flexbox and Bootstrap classes to achieve a responsive layout

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I'm encountering big troubles using both flexbox and Bootstrap responsive classes. Since an image is worth 1k words, below you have a picture of what I'd like to achieve on a desktop-size resolution and then then a mobile-size resolution.

**Desktop**

[image]

**Mobile**
[image]

I also created a fiddle which you can find on JSBin: https://jsbin.com/potunozoco/edit?html,output

I have to precise that I'm not sure if flexbox is the solution. It's just a try and this is a screen (taken from the fiddle) that shows my current progresses:

[image]

Not bad, uh? (please help me!!)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Bootstrap rows / cols nested like this..

http://www.codeply.com/go/uuZHho9U9V

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-12"> 
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1">Day</div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1">Day</div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1">Day</div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1">Day</div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1">Day</div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1">Day</div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1">Day</div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1">Day</div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1">Day</div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1">Day</div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1">Day</div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1">Day</div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1 visible-xs">Day</div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1 visible-xs">Day</div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1 visible-xs">Day</div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1 visible-xs">Day</div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1 visible-xs">Day</div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1 visible-xs">Day</div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1 visible-xs">Day</div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1 visible-xs">Day</div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1 visible-xs">Day</div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1 visible-xs">Day</div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1 visible-xs">Day</div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1 visible-xs">Day</div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1 visible-xs">Day</div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1 visible-xs">Day</div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1 visible-xs">Day</div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1 visible-xs">Day</div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1 visible-xs">Day</div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1 visible-xs">Day</div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1 visible-xs">Day</div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1 visible-xs">Day</div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1 visible-xs">Day</div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1 visible-xs">Day</div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1 visible-xs">Day</div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1 visible-xs">Day</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-12"> 
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1">Activity</div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1">Activity</div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1">Activity</div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1">Activity</div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1">Activity</div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1">Activity</div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1">Activity</div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1">Activity</div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1">Activity</div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1">Activity</div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1">Activity</div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1">Activity</div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1">Activity</div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1">Activity</div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1">Activity</div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1">Activity</div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1">Activity</div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1">Activity</div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1">Activity</div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1">Activity</div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1">Activity</div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1">Activity</div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1">Activity</div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1">Activity</div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1">Activity</div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1">Activity</div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1">Activity</div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1">Activity</div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1">Activity</div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1">Activity</div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1">Activity</div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1">Activity</div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1">Activity</div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1">Activity</div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1">Activity</div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1">Activity</div>
          </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```